# sloooow startup

Tags: neovim

sometimes nvim starts really slow. It takes several seconds to startup.
Here is my log created with `nvim --startuptime vim.log`:

```
054.603  022.454: init default mappings & autocommands
104.863  011.760  011.760: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/runtime/ftplugin.vim
138.274  033.374  033.374: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/runtime/indent.vim
157.543  000.006  000.006: require('vim.keymap')
213.618  055.999  055.999: require('lazy')
213.648  000.015  000.015: require('ffi')
213.694  000.043  000.043: require('vim.loader')
213.764  000.036  000.036: require('vim.fs')
348.492  134.779  134.743: require('lazy.stats')
368.302  007.929  007.929: require('lazy.core.util')
394.756  026.450  026.450: require('lazy.core.config')
448.761  039.454  039.454: require('lazy.core.handler')
462.983  014.216  014.216: require('lazy.core.plugin')
462.993  068.233  014.563: require('lazy.core.loader')
532.806  032.751  032.751: require('plugins.cmp')
549.641  016.723  016.723: require('plugins.neotree')
564.215  014.491  014.491: require('plugins.treesitter')
598.273  033.994  033.994: require('plugins.airline')
610.909  012.518  012.518: require('plugins.cattpucin')
633.486  022.448  022.448: require('plugins.blankline')
673.547  039.942  039.942: require('plugins.formatter')
725.158  019.359  019.359: require('plugins.lsp_cfgs')
955.197  035.840  035.840: require('vim.lsp.log')
972.291  017.090  017.090: require('vim.lsp.protocol')
1006.544  009.232  009.232: require('vim.lsp._snippet')
1011.932  005.384  005.384: require('vim.highlight')
1011.946  000.008  000.008: require('vim.F')
1011.969  039.673  025.049: require('vim.lsp.util')
1011.984  105.748  013.145: require('vim.lsp.handlers')
1048.034  036.048  036.048: require('vim.lsp.rpc')
1065.846  017.808  017.808: require('vim.lsp.sync')
1095.804  029.953  029.953: require('vim.lsp.semantic_tokens')
1115.456  019.648  019.648: require('vim.lsp.buf')
1151.465  036.004  036.004: require('vim.lsp.diagnostic')
1173.151  021.682  021.682: require('vim.lsp.codelens')
1173.209  307.212  040.322: require('vim.lsp')
1173.239  323.732  016.520: require('lspconfig.util')
1206.497  033.256  033.256: require('lspconfig.async')
1206.509  380.785  023.797: require('lspconfig.configs')
1206.512  443.102  062.316: require('lspconfig')
1213.808  007.293  007.293: require('lspconfig.server_configurations.lua_ls')
1240.787  026.782  026.782: require('lspconfig.manager')
1240.792  515.493  038.316: require('plugins.lsp_cfgs.lua')
1260.971  010.118  010.118: require('plugins.telescope.browser')
1292.051  031.049  031.049: require('plugins.telescope.telescope')
1306.239  007.103  007.103: require('plugins.sql.dadbod')
1313.861  007.420  007.420: require('plugins.comment')
1346.796  032.769  032.769: require('plugins.mason')
1381.716  034.755  034.755: require('plugins.dap')
1396.567  014.707  014.707: require('plugins.dap-ui')
1413.441  016.674  016.674: require('plugins.lua_adapter')
1468.302  008.424  008.424: require('lazy.core.handler.keys')
1481.284  012.977  012.977: require('lazy.core.handler.event')
1513.444  032.154  032.154: require('lazy.core.handler.ft')
1539.916  026.466  026.466: require('lazy.core.handler.cmd')
1540.108  000.063  000.063: require('vim.inspect')
1608.533  037.914  037.914: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua
1663.769  055.121  055.121: require('catppuccin')
1719.070  039.472  039.472: require('catppuccin.lib.hashing')
1921.953  035.783  035.783: require('vim.version')
1923.141  153.298  117.515: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-lspconfig/plugin/lspconfig.lua
1995.627  072.455  072.455: require('vim.diagnostic')
2138.927  021.823  021.823: require('ibl.utils')
2138.948  043.696  021.872: require('ibl.config')
2167.665  021.274  021.274: require('ibl.indent')
2167.688  028.739  007.465: require('ibl.hooks')
2167.715  111.013  038.578: require('ibl.highlights')
2188.970  021.252  021.252: require('ibl.autocmds')
2196.510  007.535  007.535: require('ibl.inlay_hints')
2230.369  033.854  033.854: require('ibl.virt_text')
2324.541  034.617  034.617: require('ibl.scope_languages')
2324.546  094.174  059.557: require('ibl.scope')
2324.553  328.516  060.688: require('ibl')
2373.110  011.528  011.528: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/vim-airline/autoload/airline/init.vim
2422.650  049.249  049.249: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/vim-airline/autoload/airline/parts.vim
2436.366  013.571  013.571: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/vim-airline/autoload/airline/formatter/short_path.vim
2497.848  060.705  060.705: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/vim-airline/autoload/airline/util.vim
2497.924  156.162  021.109: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/vim-airline/plugin/airline.vim
2588.997  064.478  064.478: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/plenary.nvim/plugin/plenary.vim
2648.726  008.314  008.314: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/telescope.nvim/plugin/telescope.lua
2774.390  125.638  125.638: require('telescope.builtin')
2853.512  012.122  012.122: require('telescope._extensions')
2853.518  079.061  066.938: require('telescope')
3025.247  020.502  020.502: require('telescope.state')
3113.527  014.128  014.128: require('plenary.bit')
3122.819  009.288  009.288: require('plenary.functional')
3122.853  049.426  026.011: require('plenary.path')
3122.875  082.949  033.523: require('plenary.strings')
3135.142  012.266  012.266: require('telescope.deprecated')
3219.374  028.436  028.436: require('plenary.log')
3219.410  056.419  027.983: require('telescope.log')
3276.901  020.942  020.942: require('plenary.job')
3276.911  057.500  036.557: require('telescope.utils')
3276.917  141.770  027.851: require('telescope.sorters')
3278.257  253.005  016.020: require('telescope.config')
3278.263  301.692  028.185: require('telescope.actions.state')
3278.271  327.371  025.678: require('telescope._extensions.file_browser.utils')
3373.096  023.493  023.493: require('plenary.window.border')
3387.384  014.283  014.283: require('plenary.window')
3407.016  019.628  019.628: require('plenary.popup.utils')
3407.024  092.118  034.713: require('plenary.popup')
3414.708  007.682  007.682: require('telescope.pickers.scroller')
3422.755  008.043  008.043: require('telescope.actions.utils')
3467.948  016.842  016.842: require('telescope.actions.mt')
3467.971  045.210  028.368: require('telescope.actions.set')
3522.370  021.220  021.220: require('telescope.config.resolve')
3522.378  054.404  033.184: require('telescope.pickers.entry_display')
3555.528  033.147  033.147: require('telescope.from_entry')
3555.807  277.534  036.931: require('telescope.actions')
3571.494  015.684  015.684: require('plenary.scandir')
3691.904  021.220  021.220: require('plenary.tbl')
3691.917  032.192  010.972: require('plenary.vararg.rotate')
3691.920  069.964  037.772: require('plenary.vararg')
3931.761  239.840  239.840: require('plenary.errors')
3931.786  322.522  012.718: require('plenary.async.async')
4073.355  005.918  005.918: require('plenary.async.structs')
4073.365  016.265  010.348: require('plenary.async.control')
4073.371  026.892  010.627: require('plenary.async.util')
4073.373  141.584  114.692: require('plenary.async.tests')
4073.375  501.877  037.770: require('plenary.async')
4073.467  1140.486  018.022: require('telescope._extensions.file_browser.actions')
4130.211  033.463  033.463: require('telescope._extensions.file_browser.git')
4183.313  053.097  053.097: require('telescope._extensions.file_browser.fs_stat')
4183.346  095.077  008.517: require('telescope._extensions.file_browser.make_entry')
4311.864  035.986  035.986: require('plenary.class')
4311.882  092.886  056.900: require('telescope._')
4326.491  014.607  014.607: require('telescope.make_entry')
4326.499  143.151  035.657: require('telescope.finders.async_oneshot_finder')
4377.776  015.361  015.361: require('telescope.finders.async_static_finder')
4401.717  023.936  023.936: require('telescope.finders.async_job_finder')
4401.724  075.223  035.926: require('telescope.finders')
4401.774  328.305  014.855: require('telescope._extensions.file_browser.finders')
4446.258  027.434  027.434: require('telescope.debounce')
4466.206  019.943  019.943: require('telescope.mappings')
4498.629  032.419  032.419: require('telescope.pickers.highlights')
4514.010  015.377  015.377: require('telescope.pickers.window')
4564.822  025.863  025.863: require('telescope.algos.linked_list')
4564.829  050.814  024.951: require('telescope.entry_manager')
4599.279  034.448  034.448: require('telescope.pickers.multi')
4599.295  188.131  007.696: require('telescope.pickers')
4599.299  197.523  009.392: require('telescope._extensions.file_browser.picker')
4630.295  030.994  030.994: require('telescope._extensions.file_browser.config')
4630.329  1776.809  079.500: require('telescope._extensions.file_browser')
4673.164  026.034  026.034: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/neoformat/plugin/neoformat.vim
4754.795  014.575  014.575: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/vim-vsnip/autoload/vital/vsnip.vim
4781.612  026.701  026.701: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/vim-vsnip/autoload/vital/_vsnip/VS/LSP/Position.vim
4829.670  048.007  048.007: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/vim-vsnip/autoload/vital/_vsnip.vim
4837.198  107.229  017.945: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/vim-vsnip/autoload/vsnip/snippet.vim
4860.740  023.418  023.418: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/vim-vsnip/autoload/vital/_vsnip/VS/LSP/TextEdit.vim
4897.236  036.336  036.336: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/vim-vsnip/autoload/vital/_vsnip/VS/LSP/Text.vim
4928.552  031.132  031.132: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/vim-vsnip/autoload/vital/_vsnip/VS/Vim/Buffer.vim
4964.258  035.511  035.511: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/vim-vsnip/autoload/vital/_vsnip/VS/Vim/Option.vim
4987.367  022.892  022.892: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/vim-vsnip/autoload/vital/_vsnip/VS/LSP/Diff.vim
4987.535  265.073  008.556: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/vim-vsnip/autoload/vsnip/session.vim
4987.715  277.579  012.505: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/vim-vsnip/autoload/vsnip.vim
4987.976  293.989  016.410: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/vim-vsnip/plugin/vsnip.vim
5221.710  180.666  180.666: require('cmp.utils.api')
5261.640  014.348  014.348: require('cmp.types.cmp')
5281.359  008.995  008.995: require('cmp.utils.misc')
5281.415  019.771  010.775: require('cmp.types.lsp')
5297.321  015.904  015.904: require('cmp.types.vim')
5297.326  075.612  025.590: require('cmp.types')
5323.398  026.070  026.070: require('cmp.utils.highlight')
5367.114  024.102  024.102: require('cmp.utils.debug')
5367.123  043.720  019.618: require('cmp.utils.autocmd')
5367.489  351.823  025.755: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-cmp/plugin/cmp.lua
5469.166  013.307  013.307: require('cmp.utils.char')
5469.174  055.165  041.858: require('cmp.utils.str')
5513.864  019.397  019.397: require('cmp.utils.buffer')
5513.872  035.179  015.782: require('cmp.utils.keymap')
5513.877  044.701  009.522: require('cmp.utils.feedkeys')
5561.507  026.040  026.040: require('cmp.config.mapping')
5582.001  020.490  020.490: require('cmp.utils.cache')
5630.035  014.728  014.728: require('cmp.config.compare')
5630.039  048.033  033.305: require('cmp.config.default')
5630.053  107.930  013.368: require('cmp.config')
5630.075  116.196  008.266: require('cmp.utils.async')
5690.931  029.214  029.214: require('cmp.utils.pattern')
5690.938  060.861  031.647: require('cmp.context')
5760.388  029.617  029.617: require('cmp.matcher')
5760.411  045.478  015.860: require('cmp.entry')
5760.419  069.480  024.002: require('cmp.source')
5815.414  022.528  022.528: require('cmp.utils.event')
5860.028  006.803  006.803: require('cmp.utils.options')
5860.036  019.651  012.848: require('cmp.utils.window')
5860.040  044.621  024.970: require('cmp.view.docs_view')
5873.607  013.565  013.565: require('cmp.view.custom_entries_view')
5888.684  015.073  015.073: require('cmp.view.wildmenu_entries_view')
5901.685  012.996  012.996: require('cmp.view.native_entries_view')
5915.930  014.241  014.241: require('cmp.view.ghost_text_view')
5915.945  155.523  032.499: require('cmp.view')
5916.036  522.011  020.085: require('cmp.core')
5948.631  032.493  032.493: require('cmp.config.sources')
5970.183  021.548  021.548: require('cmp.config.window')
5970.243  602.730  026.679: require('cmp')
6078.930  020.703  020.703: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-dap/plugin/dap.lua
6136.190  022.753  022.753: require('dap.utils')
6136.229  057.249  034.496: require('dap')
6136.349  121.601  043.649: require('dap')
6201.331  019.380  019.380: require('dapui.async.tasks')
6222.446  021.106  021.106: require('dapui.async.control')
6233.884  011.428  011.428: require('dapui.async.uv')
6262.193  028.304  028.304: require('dapui.async.tests')
6318.409  033.899  033.899: require('vim.ui')
6318.425  056.228  022.329: require('dapui.async.ui')
6341.076  022.650  022.650: require('dapui.async.lsp')
6341.090  183.346  024.250: require('dapui.async')
6436.146  028.389  028.389: require('dapui.config.highlights')
6436.249  058.813  030.425: require('dapui.config')
6436.258  095.166  036.352: require('dapui.util')
6468.483  032.224  032.224: require('dapui.windows.layout')
6468.494  332.142  021.407: require('dapui.windows')
6491.463  022.966  022.966: require('dapui.controls')
6491.480  519.937  043.228: require('dapui')
6521.232  014.068  014.068: require('dapui.logging')
6531.984  010.748  010.748: require('dapui.client.types')
6531.993  040.134  015.319: require('dapui.client')
6563.811  031.815  031.815: require('dap.breakpoints')
6587.434  023.607  023.607: require('dapui.client.lib')
6619.504  023.233  023.233: require('dapui.render.canvas')
6619.509  032.033  008.800: require('dapui.elements.breakpoints')
6640.444  020.918  020.918: require('dapui.components.breakpoints')
6669.291  028.815  028.815: require('dapui.elements.repl')
6683.020  013.724  013.724: require('dapui.elements.scopes')
6716.523  033.485  033.485: require('dapui.components.scopes')
6742.914  026.388  026.388: require('dapui.components.variables')
6792.126  049.197  049.197: require('dapui.elements.stacks')
6843.485  021.231  021.231: require('dapui.components.frames')
6843.490  051.350  030.119: require('dapui.components.threads')
6879.100  035.574  035.574: require('dapui.elements.watches')
6908.878  029.764  029.764: require('dapui.components.watches')
6937.578  028.683  028.683: require('dapui.elements.hover')
6976.446  038.853  038.853: require('dapui.components.hover')
6993.749  017.296  017.296: require('dapui.elements.console')
7093.902  014.796  014.796: require('Comment.config')
7158.922  028.838  028.838: require('Comment.ft')
7158.931  065.024  036.187: require('Comment.utils')
7191.601  032.667  032.667: require('Comment.opfunc')
7227.727  036.122  036.122: require('Comment.extra')
7227.734  197.090  048.480: require('Comment.api')
7227.966  222.157  025.067: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/Comment.nvim/plugin/Comment.lua
7240.406  012.354  012.354: require('Comment')
7300.993  024.168  024.168: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-web-devicons/plugin/nvim-web-devicons.vim
7369.888  033.621  033.621: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/neo-tree.nvim/plugin/neo-tree.vim
7545.449  022.010  022.010: require('neo-tree.log')
7569.093  023.640  023.640: require('neo-tree.utils.filesize.filesize')
7569.120  070.603  024.952: require('neo-tree.utils')
7569.123  199.186  128.583: require('neo-tree')
7623.462  024.254  024.254: require('neo-tree.defaults')
7631.039  007.573  007.573: require('neo-tree.setup.mapping-helper')
7665.242  014.945  014.945: require('neo-tree.collections')
7665.248  024.344  009.399: require('neo-tree.events.queue')
7665.253  034.194  009.850: require('neo-tree.events')
7707.308  028.301  028.301: require('neo-tree.sources.filesystem.lib.globtopattern')
7707.316  042.060  013.760: require('neo-tree.sources.common.file-nesting')
7729.548  022.230  022.230: require('neo-tree.ui.highlights')
7797.768  011.480  011.480: require('nui.object')
7831.864  022.078  022.078: require('nui.utils')
7831.893  034.120  012.042: require('nui.text')
7831.900  058.267  012.667: require('nui.line')
7852.498  009.285  009.285: require('nui.tree.util')
7852.512  020.610  011.326: require('nui.tree')
7881.613  013.274  013.274: require('nui.utils.buf_storage')
7894.047  012.430  012.430: require('nui.utils.autocmd')
7916.083  022.030  022.030: require('nui.utils.keymap')
7946.601  004.247  004.247: require('nui.layout.utils')
7946.607  030.520  026.273: require('nui.split.utils')
7946.630  094.116  015.862: require('nui.split')
7982.212  022.659  022.659: require('nui.popup.border')
7982.228  035.595  012.935: require('nui.popup')
8008.487  026.257  026.257: require('neo-tree.ui.popups')
8024.053  015.562  015.562: require('neo-tree.ui.windows')
8024.069  264.951  014.543: require('neo-tree.ui.renderer')
8036.372  012.301  012.301: require('neo-tree.sources.filesystem.lib.filter_external')
8047.340  010.964  010.964: require('neo-tree.sources.common.file-items')
8124.902  027.606  027.606: require('neo-tree.git.utils')
8124.908  043.658  016.052: require('neo-tree.git.status')
8177.477  052.567  052.567: require('neo-tree.git.ignored')
8177.482  117.447  021.223: require('neo-tree.git')
8177.488  130.144  012.696: require('neo-tree.sources.filesystem.lib.fs_watch')
8177.497  435.101  016.742: require('neo-tree.sources.filesystem.lib.fs_scan')
8216.448  020.941  020.941: require('nui.input')
8216.454  038.954  018.013: require('neo-tree.ui.inputs')
8216.466  486.913  012.858: require('neo-tree.sources.manager')
8298.317  030.258  030.258: require('neo-tree.command.parser')
8322.661  024.338  024.338: require('neo-tree.command.completion')
8322.666  076.400  021.804: require('neo-tree.command')
8322.669  106.201  029.801: require('neo-tree.setup.netrw')
8322.674  753.537  030.112: require('neo-tree.setup')
8350.995  027.986  027.986: require('neo-tree.setup.deprecations')
8379.894  027.525  027.525: require('neo-tree.sources.filesystem')
8474.711  047.152  047.152: require('neo-tree.sources.buffers.lib.items')
8474.718  094.815  047.663: require('neo-tree.sources.buffers')
8570.546  039.093  039.093: require('neo-tree.sources.git_status.lib.items')
8570.554  095.831  056.737: require('neo-tree.sources.git_status')
8666.421  024.098  024.098: require('neo-tree.sources.common.container')
8666.440  064.535  040.437: require('neo-tree.sources.common.components')
8666.480  095.758  031.223: require('neo-tree.sources.buffers.components')
8800.923  035.364  035.364: require('plenary')
8800.936  065.129  029.766: require('neo-tree.sources.filesystem.lib.fs_actions')
8821.220  020.281  020.281: require('neo-tree.sources.common.help')
8838.406  017.176  017.176: require('neo-tree.sources.common.preview')
8872.733  034.323  034.323: require('neo-tree.sources.common.node_expander')
8872.758  182.063  045.154: require('neo-tree.sources.common.commands')
8872.797  206.314  024.252: require('neo-tree.sources.buffers.commands')
8920.626  047.529  047.529: require('neo-tree.sources.filesystem.components')
8969.398  024.325  024.325: require('neo-tree.sources.filesystem.lib.filter')
8969.493  048.862  024.537: require('neo-tree.sources.filesystem.commands')
8992.919  023.231  023.231: require('neo-tree.sources.git_status.components')
9007.318  014.394  014.394: require('neo-tree.sources.git_status.commands')
9058.709  012.216  012.216: require('mason-core.path')
9083.320  009.935  009.935: require('mason-core.functional')
9196.428  105.594  105.594: require('mason-core.functional.data')
9196.439  113.104  007.510: require('mason-core.functional.function')
9203.511  007.034  007.034: require('mason-core.functional.relation')
9206.608  003.070  003.070: require('mason-core.functional.logic')
9206.635  147.921  014.780: require('mason-core.platform')
9317.723  111.086  111.086: require('mason.settings')
9317.727  308.649  037.426: require('mason')
9332.379  006.478  006.478: require('mason-core.functional.list')
9339.321  006.935  006.935: require('mason-core.functional.string')
9339.355  021.563  008.149: require('mason.api.command')
9342.447  003.083  003.083: require('mason-registry.sources')
9528.353  013.970  013.970: require('nvim-treesitter.utils')
9668.014  040.296  040.296: require('vim.treesitter.language')
9668.206  049.283  008.987: require('vim.treesitter.query')
9701.868  033.660  033.660: require('vim.treesitter._range')
9701.919  115.753  032.810: require('vim.treesitter.languagetree')
9701.966  119.723  003.970: require('vim.treesitter')
9702.951  174.593  054.870: require('nvim-treesitter.parsers')
9772.494  007.967  007.967: require('nvim-treesitter.compat')
9805.583  024.945  024.945: require('nvim-treesitter.ts_utils')
9805.594  033.096  008.151: require('nvim-treesitter.tsrange')
9827.651  022.055  022.055: require('nvim-treesitter.caching')
9827.663  095.528  032.410: require('nvim-treesitter.query')
9827.684  111.313  015.785: require('nvim-treesitter.configs')
9827.687  124.734  013.421: require('nvim-treesitter.info')
9837.819  010.130  010.130: require('nvim-treesitter.shell_command_selectors')
9837.843  355.377  031.950: require('nvim-treesitter.install')
9860.055  022.209  022.209: require('nvim-treesitter.statusline')
9869.912  009.852  009.852: require('nvim-treesitter.query_predicates')
9869.917  430.359  042.921: require('nvim-treesitter')
9870.216  438.669  008.309: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-treesitter/plugin/nvim-treesitter.lua
9877.858  007.452  007.452: require('nvim-treesitter.indent')
10193.779  027.936  027.936: require('nvim-treesitter.highlight')
10308.054  026.607  026.607: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/editorconfig.lua
10361.987  053.871  053.871: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/gzip.vim
10388.661  026.624  026.624: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/health.vim
10396.150  007.442  007.442: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/man.lua
10444.738  009.252  009.252: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/runtime/pack/dist/opt/matchit/plugin/matchit.vim
10444.810  048.605  039.352: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/matchit.vim
10452.586  007.744  007.744: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/matchparen.vim
10472.002  019.378  019.378: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
10492.782  020.720  020.720: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/nvim.lua
10540.763  047.919  047.919: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/rplugin.vim
10548.321  007.518  007.518: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/shada.vim
10570.101  021.737  021.737: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/spellfile.vim
10580.907  010.754  010.754: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
10589.050  008.090  008.090: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/tohtml.vim
10602.374  013.270  013.270: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/tutor.vim
10630.266  027.837  027.837: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
10735.266  021.321  021.321: require('cmp_vsnip')
10735.289  061.930  040.609: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/cmp-vsnip/after/plugin/cmp_vsnip.lua
10829.218  009.295  009.295: require('cmp_nvim_lsp.source')
10829.224  036.083  026.788: require('cmp_nvim_lsp')
10829.250  059.727  023.644: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/cmp-nvim-lsp/after/plugin/cmp_nvim_lsp.lua
10884.050  028.258  028.258: require('cmp_cmdline')
10884.070  043.370  015.111: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/cmp-cmdline/after/plugin/cmp_cmdline.lua
10922.145  013.949  013.949: require('cmp_path')
10922.176  031.295  017.346: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/cmp-path/after/plugin/cmp_path.lua
11064.353  022.355  022.355: require('cmp_buffer.timer')
11064.359  050.049  027.694: require('cmp_buffer.buffer')
11064.362  091.022  040.972: require('cmp_buffer.source')
11064.364  100.058  009.036: require('cmp_buffer')
11064.387  115.116  015.058: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/cmp-buffer/after/plugin/cmp_buffer.lua
11097.034  009.272  009.272: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/indent-blankline.nvim/after/plugin/commands.lua
11671.008  091.223  091.223: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/catppuccin/colors/catppuccin-mocha.vim
11797.607  058.443  058.443: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions.vim
11809.029  011.291  011.291: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/quickfix.vim
11843.645  034.497  034.497: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/vim-airline/autoload/airline.vim
11854.846  011.000  011.000: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/netrw.vim
11875.977  020.967  020.967: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/term.vim
11891.011  014.705  014.705: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/nvimlsp.vim
11926.083  034.904  034.904: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/whitespace.vim
11959.311  024.921  024.921: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/po.vim
11986.137  026.679  026.679: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/wordcount.vim
12014.393  028.057  028.057: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/keymap.vim
12117.549  014.963  014.963: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/searchcount.vim
12163.858  011.383  011.383: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/vim-airline/autoload/airline/section.vim
12180.145  016.113  016.113: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/vim-airline/autoload/airline/highlighter.vim
12247.368  002.862  002.862: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/vim-airline/autoload/airline/themes.vim
12247.648  041.152  038.290: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/vim-airline/autoload/airline/themes/dark.vim
12275.497  014.797  014.797: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/vim-airline/autoload/airline/builder.vim
12283.803  007.971  007.971: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/default.vim
12308.644  12170.314  1874.561: sourcing /home/t/.config/nvim/init.lua
12308.659  038.608: sourcing vimrc file(s)
12324.898  000.053  000.053: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua
12338.938  013.840  013.840: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/tabline/buffers.vim
12397.498  021.536  021.536: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/runtime/syntax/synload.vim
12397.604  058.648  037.112: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/runtime/syntax/syntax.vim
12397.618  016.418: inits 3
12449.879  052.261: reading ShaDa
12455.245  005.367: opening buffers
12455.317  000.072: BufEnter autocommands
12455.320  000.003: editing files in windows
12455.497  000.176: VimEnter autocommands
12455.531  000.034: UIEnter autocommands
12476.804  021.151  021.151: sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/runtime/autoload/provider/clipboard.vim
12476.818  000.137: before starting main loop
12485.129  008.311: first screen update
12485.132  000.003: --- NVIM STARTED ---
```

EDIT:
Here another startuptime, much faster. I've changed nothing on my init.lua:

```
088.596 085.943 043.112: sourcing /home/t/.config/nvim/init.lua
...
102.019 000.002: --- NVIM STARTED ---
```

Comment: too many plugins?

Comment: Slow loading only happens sometimes...and I don't know why. Maybe Lazy Package Manager is cheking for plugin updates but I'm not sure.

Comment: well, that find out where the differences are and ask at the package issue tracker

Comment: You can try
`strace -o strace_output.txt -s1024 -tt -yyy -f -e trace=open,read,write,close,socket,connect,sendto,recvfrom nvim
`
Maybe you see something that blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick analysis of the suspect:

```
clock   sourced self    description
12309   12170   1875    sourcing /home/t/.config/nvim/init.lua
3932    240 240 require('plenary.errors')
5222    181 181 require('cmp.utils.api')
348 135 135 require('lazy.stats')
7569    199 129 require('neo-tree')
2774    126 126 require('telescope.builtin')
1923    153 118 sourcing /home/t/.local/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-lspconfig/plugin/lspconfig.lua
4073    142 115 require('plenary.async.tests')
9318    111 111 require('mason.settings')
9196    106 106 require('mason-core.functional.data')
```

It seems that there is something wrong with your `init.lua` (~2 sec of own time seems a lot to me).
But 10 sec of loading time as an accumulation of plugin loading time seems also a lot.

Comment: On another nvim startup it needed only about 100 ms before nvim has loaded. I've changed nothing on my nvim configuration. Check out my Edit.